# Add a class the the form element (tag) of the search block form

Tags: 8, forms

How do I add a class to the form element of the search block form?

I mean, add a class to this element:

```
<form action="/search/node" method="get" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-drupal-form-fields="edit-keys"></form>
```

I've tried:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('abc'));
  }
}
```

and

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'abc';
  }
}
```

I've tried:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_form(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'search_block_form') {
    $variables['element']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('xyz'));
  }
}
```

I've looked into altering `core/modules/system/templates/form.html.twig`, which does not look like the way to go.

I'm using the Bootstrap theme as my base.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the prefix and suffix tag
like

```
$variables['element']= ['#prefix' => '<div class ="abc">',
                        '#suffix' => '</div>']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a preprocess hook to add class to a specific form:

```php
function THEME_preprocess_form(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#id'] === 'views-exposed-form-search-page-1') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'your-custom-class';
  }
}
```