# Strange behavior: Extra css classes are NOT merged with the 'Search Block' form tag classes but with those of BLOCK wrapping the form tag

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

i'm experiencing such 'strange' behavior with `Drupal (v8.7.10)` when trying to add css classes to the default `Search Form` **form tag** using `MYTHEME_form_FROM_ID_alter` hook, the classes are **NOT** merged with the form tag classes as expected but with those of the **BLOCK** wrapping the form tag itself.

this is my code:

```
function MYTHEME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form,\Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-inline';
}
```

and this is the rendered output in question

```
<div class=" form-inline " data-drupal-selector="search-block-form" novalidate="" role="search" id="block-MYTHEME-search">
  <form action="/search/node" method="get" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="edit-keys" class="sr-only">Search </label>
      <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." placeholder="Search .." data-drupal-selector="edit-keys" type="search" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-search form-control rounded-0">
    </div>
    <div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
      <input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" value="Search" class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn btn-primary rounded-0">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging for hours on drupal.org docs, i ended up with this solution

```
function mytheme_preprocess_form(&$variables) {
  // kint($variables);
  if ($variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'search_block_form') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'form-inline ';
  }
}
```

it works as expected, but `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` make more sens to me than  `hook_preprocess_form`.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straight forward PHP mistake `$form['#attributes']['class']` is an array of classes

And by doing `$form['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-inline';` you're saying forget whatever `$form['#attributes']['class']` was before its now a string that contains 'form-inline'. So you're changing the variable from an array to a string.

Long story short you should be adding your class to the existing array with:

```
 $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-inline';
```

Note the [] after ['class']

That explains why you have no classes coming out on your form. The issue about the classes on your outer div isn't related to this code and you must have something else going on too. Perhaps a block alter hook

Comment: you're right about the missing [] after ['class'], it's my fault, in fact my original snippet was this :
```
function MYTHEME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form,\Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attributes']['class'] = array('form-inline');
}
```
because  i was experiencing another strange behavior:
drupal 8 Error: [] operator not supported for strings in contextual_preprocess() (line 130 of core\modules\contextual\contextual.module).

Comment: it doesn't work, i even looked at this : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247136/add-a-class-the-the-form-element-tag-of-the-search-block-form, it seems a duplication to my thread.
bug ?

Comment: That's definitely the way to add classes to a form. It looks like something must be altering the search form block to move the classes from the form onto the block. (As i'm able to see the classes move too on my drupal install) but haven't had a chance to look why atm

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it too, it seems not working with `MYTHEME_form_FROM_ID_alter` there is another way to do so.

1. Implements `hook_theme`

```
 
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MyModule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'search_block_form' => [
      'base hook' => 'form',
      'template'  => 'form--search-block-form',
    ],
  ];
}
```

2. Create `form--search-block-form.html.twig` in templates folder of your module put in it.

```
{# add your inline-form class here #}
 <form{{ attributes.addClass('search-form', 'search-block-form', 'inline-form') }}>
  {{ children }}
</form>
```

4. Clear cash.

Comment: i was looking for 'simplest' solution without an extra twig template file. i already putted my solution (i need 2 days to mark it as accepted). anyway with your snippet you've made my day about another topic about drupal.